# Fire jQuery event on enter key press?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to submit a rails form using jQuery (Which I know little about) and have had success in setting up a form to submit on clicking the submit button and run a callback(I believe this is the correct terminology?), but I would also like to make it work when just hitting enter.

As it stands, hitting enter will submit data to the database but will not run the commands to append the div or clear the text field. How could I make this happen so it works the same for the enter key as it does the submit button? I've tried to wrap the code inside a function that will run when enter is hit but having no luck!

```
function runScript(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    msg = json.msg;
    foreign = json.foreign_speaker;
    msg_translated = json.msg_translated;
    //The HTML that we will append to the document.
    html = "<div class='msg msg" + foreign + "'>" + msg +
            "</div> <div class='msg msg" + foreign + "-translation'>" + msg_translated + "</div>"

    // Append new message.
    $('.chatmessages').append(html).fadeIn('fast');
    scrollToBottom(500)
    // Clear form with jquery.
    $('#message_msg').val('');
    $('#message_foreign_speaker').attr('checked', false);
}
```

}

I tried that with no luck.

My current, button-working, JS file:

```
var scrollToBottom = function(anim){
var myDiv = $(".wrap");
myDiv.animate({ scrollTop: myDiv[0].scrollHeight - myDiv.height() }, anim);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
scrollToBottom(0)
//JS to POST form
$('.submit').click(function() {
    var valuesToSubmit = $('.msgform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: window.location.href + '/messages', //sumbits it to the given url of the form
        data: valuesToSubmit,// { chat_id, <%= @chat.id %> },
        dataType: "JSON", // you want a difference between normal and ajax-calls
    })
    .done(refresherFunc)
    .fail(function(){
        alert("Error sending message. It would be nice to make this a flash error.");
    });
    return false; // prevents normal behaviour
})
});

var refresherFunc = function(json) {
// Get debugging goodies.
console.log(json);

// Set variables with JSON object data
msg = json.msg;
foreign = json.foreign_speaker;
msg_translated = json.msg_translated;
//The HTML that we will append to the document.
html = "<div class='msg msg" + foreign + "'>" + msg +
        "</div> <div class='msg msg" + foreign + "-translation'>" + msg_translated + "</div>"

// Append new message.
$('.chatmessages').append(html).fadeIn('fast');
scrollToBottom(500)
// Clear form with jquery.
$('#message_msg').val('');
$('#message_foreign_speaker').attr('checked', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch your form submit event with jQuery's `submit()` function and return false inside it. This function will be called any way you submit the form (clicking on submit button or pressing enter key). Returning false will prevent the browser from completing the form sumbittion which lets you do whatever you want with it.

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/vgk4wu46/